# ELF32 Static Linking (PPC 32 ABI)

Tags: c, linker, elf, static-linking, powerpc

I want to create something like static linker to append object `.o` file (compiled by ourselves) procedures to an existing executable `.elf`  file.
How this should be done?

From my point of view, we get `.text` and `.data` sections from `.o` file and append them as new sections in the `.elf` file (fixing section header table and creating new section headers).

But I don't know how add `.o` file imports in `.elf` file. Should i just get `.rel` tables and symbol tables merged in `.elf`? And how do I properly fix offsets in instructions? How can I know if an instruction should be fixed and which exactly offset should be inserted to it? (in `.o` files offsets are zeroes by default)

Comment: What's the point ? I don't understand the need to add useless code/data to the executable as the symbols in your `.o` object file won't be used by the `.elf` executable (since executables are not expected to have undefined symbols you can provide later, except for dynamic linking which is not what you want)

Comment: I'll put calls to new code manually

Answer (score 0):

You can use gcc for this purpose.

```
$ gcc -o output file1.o file2.o
```

Or do you want to write your own linker? In that case what should be the difference between the GCC and your own linker?

Comment: Yes, sort of linker. But with difference in the fact that my linker will append code from compiled object file to already linked executable file.